# How to match string/character variables in a data table in R, then print into another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, find, character, overlap

I have a data table containing a specific set of genes in one column and another set of significant genes in another column on my table. Both are character variables. How do I find the overlap of these genes and print into another column?

Example:

```r
a <- c('apple banana melon pear ', 'pear kiwi pineapple', 'avocado lime kiwi apple', 'lime pineapple banana melon')
b <- c('blah blah blah banana pear', 'blah pear blah blah kiwi', 'blah blah blah apple', 'lime blah blah blah')
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

What I want to return is `df$new_column` of `c('banana pear', 'pear kiwi', 'apple', 'lime')`

I have tried:

`df$new_column<- df$a[df$a %in% df$b]`, but I am getting the error message

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, new_column, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those strings have to be separated into words first, then we can use intersect() on pairs of those sets.

With base R perhaps something like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(a,b)
# split strings and find intersections, paste back together
df$new_column <- mapply(\(a,b) paste(intersect(a,b), collapse = " ") ,
                        strsplit(df$a, " ",),
                        strsplit(df$b, " ",))
df
#>                             a                          b  new_column
#> 1    apple banana melon pear  blah blah blah banana pear banana pear
#> 2         pear kiwi pineapple   blah pear blah blah kiwi   pear kiwi
#> 3     avocado lime kiwi apple       blah blah blah apple       apple
#> 4 lime pineapple banana melon        lime blah blah blah        lime

# all values are just plain strings:
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ a         : chr  "apple banana melon pear " "pear kiwi pineapple" "avocado lime kiwi apple" "lime pineapple banana melon"
#>  $ b         : chr  "blah blah blah banana pear" "blah pear blah blah kiwi" "blah blah blah apple" "lime blah blah blah"
#>  $ new_column: chr  "banana pear" "pear kiwi" "apple" "lime"
```

Alternatively:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

# with Tidyverse and list columns:
df_lc <- df %>% mutate(across(c(a,b), ~ str_split(.x, " "))) %>% 
  mutate(new_col = map2(a,b, ~ intersect(.x,.y)))

# now we have list columns:
df_lc["new_col"]
#>        new_col
#> 1 banana, pear
#> 2   pear, kiwi
#> 3        apple
#> 4         lime

# when printing a tibble it's bit more evident:
as_tibble(df_lc)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   a         b         new_column  new_col  
#>   <list>    <list>    <chr>       <list>   
#> 1 <chr [5]> <chr [5]> banana pear <chr [2]>
#> 2 <chr [3]> <chr [5]> pear kiwi   <chr [2]>
#> 3 <chr [4]> <chr [4]> apple       <chr [1]>
#> 4 <chr [4]> <chr [4]> lime        <chr [1]>

str(df_lc)
#> 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ a         :List of 4
#>   ..$ : chr  "apple" "banana" "melon" "pear" ...
#>   ..$ : chr  "pear" "kiwi" "pineapple"
#>   ..$ : chr  "avocado" "lime" "kiwi" "apple"
#>   ..$ : chr  "lime" "pineapple" "banana" "melon"
#>  $ b         :List of 4
#>   ..$ : chr  "blah" "blah" "blah" "banana" ...
#>   ..$ : chr  "blah" "pear" "blah" "blah" ...
#>   ..$ : chr  "blah" "blah" "blah" "apple"
#>   ..$ : chr  "lime" "blah" "blah" "blah"
#>  $ new_column: chr  "banana pear" "pear kiwi" "apple" "lime"
#>  $ new_col   :List of 4
#>   ..$ : chr  "banana" "pear"
#>   ..$ : chr  "pear" "kiwi"
#>   ..$ : chr "apple"
#>   ..$ : chr "lime"
```

Input:

```r
a <- c('apple banana melon pear ', 'pear kiwi pineapple', 'avocado lime kiwi apple', 'lime pineapple banana melon')
b <- c('blah blah blah banana pear', 'blah pear blah blah kiwi', 'blah blah blah apple', 'lime blah blah blah')
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>